# Is it possible to have both the contract and the stub testes at the same module?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

It seems that the stubs are generated too late for the tests to use them.  and since I get in the build system following error:

For groupId [example.com] artifactId [my-service] and classifier [stubs] the version was not resolved! The following exceptions took place [org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata example.com:my-service/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/jenkins/.m2...)

at a later stage I get: 
--- spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.0.0.RC1:generateStubs (default-generateStubs) @my-service

Answer (score 0):

I don't really follow what you're trying to do, but you can first run the maven / gradle goal to generate and install the stubs and then run the tests. But that sounds like a smell that in your tests you need your own stubs? That sounds like a bad design

Comment: I have a service with REST API (Spring Boot with MVC) and I have a client (Feign based) module.

Comment: Ok, and now what? Just use both stub runner starter with rest docs. You'll get stubs and use stubs

Comment: BTW i think you're misunderstanding the exception. It's not saying that your stub is missing. The stub of your consumers is missing

Comment: I have a service with REST API (Spring Boot + MVC) module and client (Feign based) module, I want to do most of the testing with contracts and stubs and still do few E2E integration tests on some cases, for these integration tests the service is dependent on the client in test scope, I have the contracts in the service module, now I want to do the client tests using stubs, so put them in the service module and now I get the above issue, I was thinking of running 2 maven steps or adding a module just for tests, but is there other solution or recommended project structure?